# SAS quote a string for label usage

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to QUOTE the following string '%LLY+' and use it as Y-axis in the plot.

But I am always getting warning message from SAS saying that

WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro LLY not resolved.

or NOTE: The quoted string currently being processed has become more than 262 characters long.  You might have unbalanced quotation marks.
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro LLY not resolved.

But actually the '%LLY' is not macro variable. My question is how to quote this without getting any warning message?

```
data _null_;
 CALL SYMPUTX('var1','%LLY+');
 run;
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. Show how you are trying to use the macro variable VAR1 that your code is creating.  The message is being caused by that code that you have not yet shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes.
When you have double quotes SAS will try and resolve that as a macro.

```
data _null_;
 CALL SYMPUTX('var1','%LLY+');
run;
```

EDIT:

```
data _null_;
  %*option 1;
 CALL SYMPUTX('var1',%nrstr('%LLY+'));
 
 %*option 2;
 var = '%LLY+';
 call symputx('var2', var);
 
  %*option 3;
 call symputx('var3', '%LLY+');
run;

data demo;
var1 = symget('var1');
var2 = symget('var2');
var3 = symget('var3');
run;

proc print data=demo;
run;
```

Here's the log showing no issues, if you're getting errors they're from somewhere else.

```
69         data _null_;
 70           %*option 1;
 71          CALL SYMPUTX('var1',%nrstr('%LLY+'));
 72         
 73          %*option 2;
 74          var = '%LLY+';
 75          call symputx('var2', var);
 76         
 77           %*option 3;
 78          call symputx('var3', '%LLY+');
 79         run;
 
 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.00 seconds
       
 
 80         
 81         data demo;
 82         var1 = symget('var1');
 83         var2 = symget('var2');
 84         var3 = symget('var3');
 85         run;
 
 NOTE: The data set WORK.DEMO has 1 observations and 3 variables.
 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.00 seconds
       
 
 86         
 87         proc print data=demo;
 88         run;
 
 NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set WORK.DEMO.
 NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINT used (Total process time):
       real time           0.01 seconds
       cpu time            0.02 seconds
```

And here's the output:

> Obs   var1    var2    var3
>
> 1     %LLY+   %LLY+   %LLY+

EDIT2:

If you used %PUT this is what you would get:

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro LLY not resolved.
 68         
 69         
 70             %Put &var1.;
 %LLY+
 71             %put &var2.;
 WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro LLY not resolved.
 %LLY+
 72             %put &var3.;
 WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro LLY not resolved.
 %LLY+
 73         
 74         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 84
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried using single quote, but still get the same warning message.

Comment: If you're getting errors it's not from the single quotes, it's somewhere else. Please edit your question, not my answer.

Comment: May bad, sorry for that, I will try your suggestions, thanks!!!